# Can a strictly increasing convex function $F$ meet a line segment in 3 places, without being linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

$$(1) F:[0,1] \rightarrow\, [0,1]\,$$

Where  a $F$ is  a  $(C)$  continuous  convex function 
$$\forall t\in [0,1];\forall(x,y)\in[0,1];\,F(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tF(x)+(1-t)\times F(y)$$.
where $F$ satisfies  $(E)$ .
$$(E)\,F(1)\geq 1\,\,,  F(0)\leq 0\,\,,\&\,   \exists \,\,\text{some third interior fixed point} \,m\in\text{dom}(F);\,F(m)\geq m\,\,\text{where}; 0 \neq m \neq 1$$.

(2) $$F:[0,1] \leftrightarrow\, [0,1]\,$$.
Where $F$ is a  bi-jective self map ,of the unit interval that satisfies. $(A), (B) \land (SC)$ below.

$$(A) \text{F is 1-auto-diffeo-morphophism of unit interval}$$, 
Once continuous derivatives of $F$ and its inverse function.
$$(A)F(0)=0,\, F(1)=1\land F(m)=m\,\text{where} \,m\in (0,1)$$.

$$(SC)\text{and  star convex at 0}: $$.
$$(SC)\forall(x\in(0,1)):F(tx)\leq t\times F(x)$$.

Can function (1) $F(x)$ meet with a line segment in three distinct points **without  $F(x)$  being** $F(x)=x$?

**Answer no**.
What about star convex function $(2)$
My answer: $$\forall x\in [0,1];x\geq m):F(x)=x$$

Caveat: If ,yes, Suppose we replace $(SC)$ with midpoint -star convexity at $0$

$$\forall(x)\in [0,1]:F(\frac{1}{2}\times x)\leq \frac{1}{2}\times F(x)$$.
where $$m\in \text{Q}\cap [0,1]$$?.

I presume, but do know that the answer is also no here as it is for a strictly monotonic increasing that is continousthat is 2- midpoint convex function with three fixed points.

Comment: In geometric terms, convexity of a function means that, for all $x<y$ the graph $\lbrace (t,f(t)): x\le t\le y\rbrace$ is below the line segment joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$.Assume that there is $z$ with $f(z)<z$ and apply the above to one of the intervals $[0,z]$ or $[z,1]$ which contains $1/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibility is $F(x) = x$. Here is an argument without assuming differentiability. For greater generality, replace $x^* \in (0,1)$ as the third point where $F(x^*) = x^*$ instead of $x^*=1/2$.

By convexity, for any $x$ in $(0,1)$ with $x\ne 1/2$, the incremental ratio
$$R(x) = \frac{F(x) - F(1/2)}{x-(1/2)}$$
is increasing, so $R(0) \le R(x) \le R(1)$.

When $F(x) = x$ for $x=0, 1/2, 1$, we have
$$R(0) = R(1) = 1$$
which squeezes $R(x)=1$ and implies $F(x) = x$.

Comment: @William Balthes The argument above does not assume differentiability and holds for $F(0.6) = 0.6$ replacing $0.5$ with $0.6$.

Comment: when you edited the post and removed the redundant assumptions; was bi-jectivity redundant already given the convexity,and strict monotone increasingness and the other conditions, (that either differentiability or convexity alone implies continuity and as a result of the conditions surjectivity and thus F bijective as its already injective) or was this because i used $\Leftrightarrow$

Comment: @William Balthes: Strict increasing implies injective. If you add $F(0)=)$ with $F(1)=1$, you have subjectivity as well.

Comment: yes this follows from the intermediatel value theorem doesnt given the continuity implied by convexity?

Comment: Dear @MLC, does subjectivity mean the same thing as surjective?

Comment: I presume monotonicity increasing at very least is required?

Comment: @William Balthes I fail to get your comment, sorry --- you have assumed increasing in the title of your OP. What are you referring to?

Comment: I originally presumed in the question strict monotone increasing. I am now wondering whether the result holds if convex and continuous F is only presumed Monotonic increasing with F(1)=1 F(0)=0, and F(0.5)=0.5 or any arbitrary fixed point, without even also assume once differentiability. ANd moreover, would this give this result for midpoint convexity. These functions have issues with continuity at 1 even if measurable. However this is precisely where it will equal the identity (as as I can see) for all rational x >0.5 before continuity is presumed; that is if indeed midpoint convex F

Comment: is continuity at 1, yet as it agrees with a continuous function on the open interval [0.5, 1]=x over a dense subset and F is monotone it will just be the identity on $(0.5, 1)$ and continuous there.

Comment: Now given it just is the identity function on that subinterval can (rather then being merely continuous  on that sub-interval which it already is, on [0,1) if F is monotone increasing /measurable F:[0,1] to [0,1] and F(0)=0 and F(1)=1 and F is midpoint convex; does the fact that it is the identity allow one to use the identity function in the limit towards 1 (of course continuity on [0.5,1) by itself would not imply anything about continuity at 1,

Comment: This string of comments is way too long. Please post a new question, perhaps with a reference to the present one.

Comment: Dear Mlc I apologize for this Iw ill do so, I was just wondering about result which was originally an answer to my question where F was assumed strictly monotone increasing. I was wondering if you only need monotone incresing

Comment: I presume that non-negativity need not be explicitly presumed as it is in the question above